# super low performance when client.query(query).to_dataframe(create_bqstorage_client=True) run in Docker container

Tags: google-bigquery

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas as pd
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
import time
credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file(r'xxxxx.json')
# Create a BigQuery client.
client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials)

query="""
  SELECT *
FROM `xxx.gdfp_dataset.p_NetworkBackfillImpressions_xxxxx`
WHERE 
  TIMESTAMP_MICROS(TimeUsec2) BETWEEN
  TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 22 HOUR) AND
  TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 21 HOUR)
"""
# Execute the query and convert the results to a pandas DataFrame.
start_time = time.time()
print("Querying BigQuery",'start time',time.time())
df = client.query(query).to_dataframe(create_bqstorage_client=True)
print("Querying BigQuery",'end time',time.time())
#print(f"Insertion took {time.time() - start_time} seconds")
```

Docker file:

```
# Use the official Python image from the Docker Hub
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
# Make a directory for our application
WORKDIR /app
# Copy over the requirements file
COPY requirements.txt .
# Install pip dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
# Copy the rest of our application code
COPY . /app
# Run the application
CMD ["python", "-u", "gdfp_main.py"]
```

When I run this in local machine it take 22 seconds
When I run this in local machine in Docker container it take 363 seconds
When I run this on AWS Fargate(ECS) 16gb memory 2048 cpu it take around 350 seconds too!

Please help thanks

Comment: Could you try some optimization in your select query? For more information, you can refer to these [link1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#avoid_select_) and [link2](https://towardsdatascience.com/14-ways-to-optimize-bigquery-sql-for-ferrari-speed-at-honda-cost-632ec705979).

Answer (score 0):

Potential workaround:

- install `google-cloud-bigquery-storage`

I have the same issue here, but managed to run it faster with the following dependencies versions:

```
google-api-core==2.11.1
google-auth==2.22.0
google-cloud-bigquery==3.11.3
google-cloud-bigquery-storage==2.22.0
google-cloud-storage==2.10.0
pyarrow==12.0.1
db-dtypes==1.1.1
pandas==2.0.3
```